# How can I call asynchronously a method only when other async method finishes working in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, dispatch-async

I'm implementing `socket.io` library for `swift`.

There is a method related to connecting to the server that looks as follows:

```
func connectToServerWithNickname(nickname: String) {
        socket.emit("connectUser", nickname)
}
```

The `socket.emit` calls:

```
private func _emit(data: [AnyObject], ack: Int? = nil) {
    dispatch_async(emitQueue) {
        guard self.status == .Connected else {
            self.handleEvent("error", data: ["Tried emitting when not connected"], isInternalMessage: true)
            return
        }

        let packet = SocketPacket.packetFromEmit(data, id: ack ?? -1, nsp: self.nsp, ack: false)
        let str = packet.packetString

        DefaultSocketLogger.Logger.log("Emitting: %@", type: self.logType, args: str)

        self.engine?.send(str, withData: packet.binary)
    }
}
```

as you can see it's all packed in `dispatch_async`. I would like to post an `NSNotification` as soon as this method is done and my app connects to the server, sth like:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(setConnectionStatus, object: self)
```

So my question is - how should I modify my `connectToServerWithNickname` method so that it calls my `nsnotificationcenter` when everything goes correct?

Comment: `as soon as this method is done and my app connects to the server` Does this mean it could be done after the `self.engine?.send(str, withData: packet.binary)` line, or would you have to wait for the server response to be sure you're connected before sending the notification?

Comment: I know there's the `ack` data that confirms the connection was successful, so for me it would be perfect to have this information and then call the `NSNotificationCenter`. Otherwise - if that's not possible - I can stay with the first option though

Comment: do you not have socket listeners, like onEvents, which would fire when you receive a connected message?

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I followed this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/ and they didn't mention there about any socket listeners :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you stated you are using socket.IO

When you make your instance of the socket before you connect you will have

```
var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.XXX:3000")!)
```

then after this put

```
    socket.on("connect") { (data, ack) -> Void in
         // This will be fired once your socket connects.
    }
```

EDIT:

For individual emits, you would keep a pointer to your socket and use

```
     let json = ["things_i_need_to_send" : stuff]

    socket.emitWithAck(Place_i_need_to_send_to, json)(timeoutAfter: 3) { data in
       //This is called on completion
    }
```

So using your above example.

```
    socket.emitWithAck(connectUser, nickname)(timeoutAfter: 3) { data in
       //This is called on completion
    }
```

Comment: is there a way of checking the completion handler here?

Comment: thank you! one last question - what is `timeoutAfter` here?

Comment: the amount of time in seconds before the call should timeout and be deemed failed.